# unable to fetch data using Get method in INVOKEHTTP processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: api, apache-nifi

I used POST method to get token from an API using 'invokehttp' processor in Apache Nifi and successfully got the token. I tried another 'invokehttp' processor with GET method to extract the actual data, but I am getting blank output file with status success.  When I use the same details using POSTMAN, it gives me expected data.

Comment: Obviously, your request in postman is not the same.

Comment: I believe that you got token in the body response. How do you need to provide it to your hey call? As header attribute? Pleased provide both calls as curl. You can export curl calls from postman.